# How to post data from json api in to list in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

i have this model from generator web site,
but i don't know how to post and get data from api url in to this model.

https://github.com/jetrinn/ienergywhiz/blob/master/Site.dart [this is the model](https://github.com/jetrinn/ienergywhiz/blob/master/json)

[And this is example json data](https://github.com/jetrinn/ienergywhiz/blob/master/json)

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data follow docs.

Comment: Thank mate but Can i do like a doc with my json that have array object.

Comment: this docs is similar for array objects. You just need to show array data in a listview or something similar.